# Debugging CPU consumption and dragging lag in MapBox Android 8.x

Tags: rendering, mapbox-android

I'm using MapBox for Android v8.3.0-beta.1 (similar results on the previous 8.x versions), and the problem I'm facing is that when I drag/pan the map around I see noticeable lag as if camera does not follow the movements. It results in very poor user experience, and besides, CPU load jumps often to over 100% for given process.
Admittedly, the hardware is the low-end spec. Nevertheless, I'd like to improve the UX and fix panning performance if possible. Ideally if I can diagnose what causes the lags.

I've disabled all the animations, tried the simplest app with just a map, tried to enable layers one by one. It didn't make significant difference, the map is still jerky from time to time.
Apparently, versions prior to 7.x performed better.

Comment: Any updates? I have the same problem

Comment: Not really yet. I'm checking what happens with smaller tiles at the moment.

Comment: Try disabling the location component on your map view, it solved my problem

Comment: Thanks, but I have custom layer instead of standard location component as there are few other layers depending on location so it'd be worse otherwise. In the past I had to disable all animations to make it all work smoother. Out of interest - what do you mean by "disabling location component", ie not enabling it in the first place or somehow disabling explicitly? If the latter - how?

Comment: I meant not enabling it in the first place.